# Send docusign on behalf of user

Tags: docusign

When sending Docusign envelopes to Customers, currently all envelopes and communications sent through Docusign utilise the Docusign Integration user account on Salesforce which is matched with an integration user account in Docusign.

The expectation is that the sender email/ sent by email should be set to the user who clicks on the 'Send via Docusign' button on quote.

I have enabled the SOBO functionality in Docusign but I am not sure how to proceed further. Please suggest.

Comment: Wouldnt that mean each user need to have docusign licence and probably thats a cost?

Comment: Yes, each user already has a license and that adds to the cost but this is the current requirement.

Comment: as mentioned in the docs https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-admin-guide-send-on-behalf-of the SOBO is enabled by default for new installations, if it isn't your case, you must maybe go to the permissions page for the Integration user and selecting the Account Wide-Rights and Send On Behalf Of Rights (API) options.